# Easiest way to get a bibtex citation of a paper that scholar is still not showing its proper published paper?

Tags: citations, google-scholar, latex

For some reason, even papers published in very places like ICLR, still don't get updated on scholar, for example "HOW POWERFUL ARE GRAPH NEURAL NETWORKS?" paper still shows as arxiv in scholar.

so what is the easiest way for me to get the bibtex citation of these type of papers that scholar still don't update their published place, other than writing it myself? (I know, I'm lazy)

Comment: Most publishers that provide bibtex records (including Google Scholar) provide _terrible_ bibtex records, with inconsistent titles/abbreviations/capitalization, syntax errors (especially near names with accents or mathematics in titles), redundant/extraneous data, hyphens instead of dashes between page numbers, and so on.  Moreover, bibtex records from different sources use different standards---some abbreviating titles and others not, for instance.  Even if you get the record from the publisher (or Google), you will have to correct it.  It's honestly easier just to type it yourself.

Comment: Maybe not so useful to the OP, but for the benefit of others who come across this question in the future: in (pure) mathematics, MathSciNet and zbMATH are the go-to sources for bibliographic information on papers that have been published, and they actually provide pretty good bibtex records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One technique for me (currently writing my PhD thesis, so did this a lot of times recently, works more than 95% of the time) is to google and go to the conference/journal/openreview page and get the citation there. I look for a button called "cite" or "export citation" or sometimes it is hidden under another button, e.g. "tools". Usually I first skim the page for a couple of seconds, then hit ctrl+f and search for the phrase "cite", if it does not find anything then I look for different buttons such as "tools"...

For your example: If you google ([here](https://www.google.com/search?q=HOW%20POWERFUL%20ARE%20GRAPH%20NEURAL%20NETWORKS%3F&rlz=1C1SQJL_enGB920GB920&oq=HOW%20POWERFUL%20ARE%20GRAPH%20NEURAL%20NETWORKS%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i61j69i60l2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)) the name of the paper the first hit after the arxiv one is the openreview webpage: https://openreview.net/forum?id=ryGs6iA5Km. On this page there is a small button "Show Bibtex" right under the title. When you click on it it opens a small window with the bibtex entry as written below. This takes me about 10-15 seconds, definitely faster than writing it yourself!

"
@inproceedings{
xu2018how,
title={How Powerful are Graph Neural Networks?},
author={Keyulu Xu and Weihua Hu and Jure Leskovec and Stefanie Jegelka},
booktitle={International Conference on Learning Representations},
year={2019},
url={https://openreview.net/forum?id=ryGs6iA5Km},
}
"